# Google's PHP recaptcha in RTL orientation - css issue

Tags: php, recaptcha

It appears that styling (or HTML layout) doesn't seem to work properly for PHP recaptcha in RTL orientation (v 1.0):

[image]

Is it possible to fix this without hacking / manipulating CSS manually? I can't seem to find an option to get back RTL oriented captcha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't fix it with CSS, here's a jQuery 'hack' that makes it look properly.

```
/**
 * Used for recaptcha in RTL orientation.
 * Replaces cell td1 position inside row
 * with td2's position. The problem appears with
 * edges appearing improperly in RTL orientation.
 * This function swaps position of td1 with td2 , thus
 * correcting the edges which look
 * malformed.
 * @param {type} td1
 * @param {type} td2
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
var correctCaptchaLayout = function (td1, td2)
{
    if (typeof ($(td1)) === 'undefined' ||
            typeof ($(td2)) === 'undefined') {
        return false;
    }
    var td1Html = $(td1)[0].outerHTML;
    var td2Html = $(td2)[0].outerHTML;
    var row = $(td1).parent();

    td1.remove();
    td2.remove();

    row.prepend($(td2Html));
    row.append($(td1Html));
    return true;
}
```

The captcha layout is fixed by calling correctCaptchaLayout() twice, once for each of the malformed row.